# How to call JSON files via jQuery in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, asset-pipeline

I am building a simple wayfinding app for a building in Rails using the [Mapplic](http://www.mapplic.com/) jQuery plugin.

The script expects a JSON file that it calls like so:

```
$('#floor-5').mapplic({
  source: 'floor-5.json',
  height: 1000,
  minimap: false,
  sidebar: true,
  hovertip: true,
  developer: false,
  maxscale: 3
});
```

I have the JSON file in `app/assets/json/floor-5.json`.

I think the jQuery script is trying to use AJAX, which I am aware is problematic in Rails.

The JS and CSS files are all being properly called via the asset pipeline, but I'm not sure how to properly access the required JSON file via the asset pipeline.

The JSON file then loads the image it wants to use via AJAX:

```
{
    "mapwidth":"1080",
    "mapheight": "1000",
    "levels": [
    {
        "id" : "floor-5",
        "map" : "/assets/images/floor-5.png",
        "minimap" : "/assets/images/floor-5.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I reconcile these AJAX calls with the asset pipeline?

Comment: How is AJAX problematic for Rails? Having trouble making sense of this question. Are you trying to reference a JavaScript object in a static file?

Comment: NickM, I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how this particular jQuery plugin is referencing files, and it doesn't make sense to me within the Rails asset pipeline. So that makes it harder for me to formulate a question. The jQuery is in a view referencing a source JSON file using AJAX, and the JSON file is referencing an image file again with AJAX. This is an unfamiliar structure for me and I can't quite wrap my mind around it. I can't get this to work the way it's supposed to, which should result in the image loading in the DOM with some additional controls laid overtop the image.

Comment: Update: Solved. The problem wasn't AJAX it was invalid JSON. I used this JSON validator and fixed the errors: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have invalid JSON. If your assets are all in the correct folders within the Rails asset pipeline, Rails should have no problem finding those files using AJAX. However, if you have invalid JSON it will throw the same error as if it's not able to load the file at all. Use a JSON validator and see if that fixes the problem: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/